# Type of Character generated by UUID

Tags: java, uuid

1. Does **java.util.UUID** generates special characters?
2. What are the type of each character (eg- Uppercase, lower case, digits) generated by UUID.

Answer (score 78):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> Does java.util.UUID generates special characters?

No. A UUID is **actually a 128-bit value**, not text.

A UUID’s textual representation is canonically a string of hex digits (0-9, a-f, A-F) plus hyphens.

---

You asked:

> What are the type of each character (eg- Uppercase, lower case, digits) generated by UUID.

As required by the UUID spec, any a-to-f characters in the hex string representing a UUID value **must be in all lowercase**. But violations abound.

## UUID ≠ text

To clarify, a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is actually *a 128-bit value*, not text, not digits.

You could think of them as 128-bit unsigned integers. But they are not actually numbers, as certain bit positions have semantics, specific meanings. Which bits have which meanings varies by [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants) and by [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) of UUID.

## Hex string

Humans don't do well reading and writing 128 bits as 128 `1` and `0` characters. When a UUID needs to be written for human consumption, we use a base-16 [Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (digits `0`-`9` and letters `a`-`f`) string. We use 32 hex characters grouped with 4 hyphens to represent those 128 bits in a total of 36 characters. For example:

> 550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000

## No "Special" Characters

As for "special characters" mentioned in the Question, you will only see these 23 possible characters in a hex-string representation of a UUID:

> abcdefABCDEF1234567890-

## Lowercase Required By Spec

The latest [international spec](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.667/en) dated 2008-08 states (emphasis mine):

> 6.5.4 Software generating the hexadecimal representation of a UUID **shall not use upper case** letters.
> NOTE – It is recommended that the hexadecimal representation used in all human-readable formats be restricted to lower-case letters. Software processing this representation is, however, required to accept both upper and lower case letters as specified in 6.5.2.

### Violations Common

However, Microsoft, Apple, and others commonly violate the lowercase rule. At one point Microsoft released software that generated *mixed case* (using both upper- and lowercase), apparently an unintended feature.

So do as the spec says:

- Use lowercase for output.
- Tolerate either lowercase or uppercase for input.

The Java documentation for the [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class’ [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString--) method documents in [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) that uppercase is allowed when generating a string, in contradiction to the UUID standard specification. However the actual behavior of the class and its `toString` method in the [Oracle implementation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) for Java 8 is correct, using lowercase for output but tolerating either uppercase or lowercase for input.

Input in either lower-/uppercase:

```
UUID uuidFromLowercase = UUID.fromString ( "897b7f44-1f31-4c95-80cb-bbb43e4dcf05" ); 
UUID uuidFromUppercase = UUID.fromString ( "897B7F44-1F31-4C95-80CB-BBB43E4DCF05" );
```

Output to lowercase only:

```
System.out.println ( "uuidFromLowercase.toString(): " + uuidFromLowercase );
System.out.println ( "uuidFromUppercase.toString(): " + uuidFromUppercase );
```

> uuidFromLowercase.toString(): 897b7f44-1f31-4c95-80cb-bbb43e4dcf05

> uuidFromUppercase.toString(): 897b7f44-1f31-4c95-80cb-bbb43e4dcf05

See this [code run live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/yAF5Um).

## Nil value

When the UUID is not yet known, you can use a special UUID consisting of all zeros.

> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

## Example Values

You can see some examples of UUID values by using any of the many web sites that generate values. For example:

- https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

Or use a command-line tool. Nearly every operating system comes bundled with such a tool. On [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS), launch [Terminal.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29) and type `uuidgen`.

Answer (score 10):

The javadoc for [java.util.UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) links to [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) which says

> ```
>   Each field is treated as an integer and has its value printed as a
>   zero-filled hexadecimal digit string with the most significant
>   digit first.  The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as
>   lower case characters and are case insensitive on input.
> ```

So no, it will not generate special characters.

Answer (score 6):

A UUID doesn't consist of characters, unless you ask it to be converted into a string. At that point, it will be turned into a string consisting of hex characters and hyphens, [as described by the docs for `UUID.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString%28%29).

(It's not documented whether the hex digits will be upper or lower case.)

Comment: produces lowercase characters

Comment: @kommradHomer: That may be true for a particular implementation, but a different implementation could produce upper case characters and it would still be valid.

Comment: so true ,just wanted to provide a side note as the question was about JAVA and you have linked the JAVA doc , i thought i could point what JAVA does all along

Comment: @kommradHomer: The point is that you've said what *one* implementation of Java (not JAVA, btw) does. Have you checked that *all* of them do the same thing?

Comment: but you were linking oracle Java, that's what i have noted for

Answer (score 1):

According to [Internet RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122),

> Each field is treated as an integer and has its value printed as a
> zero-filled hexadecimal digit string with the most significant
> digit first.  The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are **output as
> lower case characters** and are case insensitive on input.

If you respect internet standard, always use lower-case.

Though BNF defines upper-case letters, it is for input, not output.