# Unable to populate some checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One of my forms has eight sets of checkboxes. The form is populated from a database using AJAX and jQuery. Most of the checkbox sets load correctly but four do not. There seems to be no difference between the code used in each case and after some hours of testing I can't find out what's causing these four to fail.

One difference is that the four that fail use UUIDs as values. When I change the values to numbers in these the code works correctly. However, two of the other checkbox sets also use UUIDs and they work fine. The failing four have different and more complicated formatting so I've removed the formatting to no avail.

This is the format for all the checkboxes. This example is copied from one of the failing checkbox sets (there are 83 members altogether but I'll spare you the complete list):

```
<input id='interest1' name='interest[]' type='checkbox' value='74095951-F0EF-441C-85F4-949304FF6B89' />
<label for="interest1">Civil rights</label>
<input id='interest2' name='interest[]' type='checkbox' value='3D8A60AC-732F-4522-A9A7-7E564F16C5DA' />
<label for="interest2">Domestic violence</label>
```

This is the jQuery code that sets the state of all the checkbox sets, the ones that work and those that don't:

```
if($.isArray(value)){
  for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="' + key + '"][value="' + value[i] + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
  }          
}
```

In each case, `value` is a simple array.

Does anyone have any ideas for tests I can make to identify the cause?

Comment: Your code works in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6drokjy3/

Comment: Do not interact with properties using `.attr`. Use `.prop` for properties. (this may or may not help your situation, but better to use correct method regardless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

The look-up tables used to generate the four sets of checkboxes causing the problem have their UUIDs in upper case. But the test data is in lower case.

My apologies for bothering the list with this. I am deeply embarrassed.

I shall now convert all the UUIDs to lower case, as I learn from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13833488/9428542 is the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `each` function to iterate over the array. There's no need to quote attribute values in CSS selectors, and as mentioned in comments you should use `prop` to set boolean attributes such as `checked`, `disabled`, etc.

```js
var key = 'interest';
var value = ['74095951-F0EF-441C-85F4-949304FF6B89', '3D8A60AC-732F-4522-A9A7-7E564F16C5DA'];

$.each(value, function(i, v) {
    $('input[type=checkbox][name^=' + key + '][value=' + v + ']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='interest1' name='interest[]' type='checkbox' value='74095951-F0EF-441C-85F4-949304FF6B89' />
<label for="interest1">Civil rights</label>
<input id='interest2' name='interest[]' type='checkbox' value='3D8A60AC-732F-4522-A9A7-7E564F16C5DA' />
<label for="interest2">Domestic violence</label>
<input id='interest3' name='interest[]' type='checkbox' value='3D8A60AC-732F-4522-A9A7-7E564F16C5DB' />
<label for="interest3">Some other thing</label>
```